# Calculate heading margin based on height

Tags: html, css

I have a body text with `line-height: 22px`, and I want to use heading with `line-height: 26px`. Also, I define `margin-bottom: 18px` to keep vertical rhythm. But, if heading holds 2 lines, its margin needs to be recalculated (in my case: `14 = 66-26*2`).

If possible, how to perform it in pure css?

Thanks.

Comment: You can' calculate using pure CSS dependent on the element size because this size is dynamically. You need at least JavaScript for this.

Comment: Impossible to have conditional statements in CSS. Logic is not supported. So the best you can do would be a JavaScript function to control the logic and add a class if necessary.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc this might be something you'd want to look into.

Calc can actually do some math for you but it's buggy as hell.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, the *top-left-corners* of your containers should always be 66px from the prior no matter the content?

Then just give the container in question a height of `66px`, without any margin?

```
h1 {
    line-height:22px;
    height:66px;
    border: 1px solid red; /* visibility purpose */
    margin:0px;
}

<h1>foo</h1>
<h1>bar<br/>baz</h1>
<h1>foo</h1>
<h1>foo</h1>
```

This looks like a "recalculated margin" for the second headline.(if the borders i added for visibility purpose are removed)

https://jsfiddle.net/qbvdorwn/

Comment: Thanks for answer, the goal is heading, with height divisible to baseline,  with no matter of the content. If heading holds 1 line - `height:26px;margin-bottom:18px`. If heading holds 2 lines - `height:52px;margin-bottom:14px ` and so on.